# Bottom Border in UiTextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Actually i have created Border in Textfiled by using this code.

```
 CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];

bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.frame.size.height - 1, self.layer.frame.size.width, 1.0f);

bottomBorder.backgroundColor = self.BorderColor.CGColor;

[self.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

Everything is working fine  upto iphone 5s  but when i run in iphone 6 and above it's border size decrease. like if width of textfield is 120 border show only upto 100 . Don't know how to deal with That. Please Guide me through it

Comment: add code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` .. may be works for you

Comment: Write `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` after `[self.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deal with `CALayer` then Try this following life cycle method.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.frame.size.height - 1, self.layer.frame.size.width, 1.0f);
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = self.BorderColor.CGColor;
    [self.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the border layer in an instance variable and update its frame in `layoutSubviews`.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews() {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.frame.size.height - 1, self.layer.frame.size.width, 1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one function, and call where u want.

```
 -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self setBottomBorder:self.txtfield];
}
-(void)setBottomBorder:(UITextField*)textfield
{
    //bottom border
    CALayer *BottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
    BottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, textfield.frame.size.height-1, textfield.frame.size.width, 1f);
    BottomBorder.backgroundColor =GreenColor.CGColor;

    [textfield.layer addSublayer:BottomBorder];
}
```